# change dimensions from point coordinate to lat lon in xarray Dataset

Tags: dataset, netcdf, python-xarray

I have this dataset with as possible coordinates stations, lat, lon and time. Right now the dataset uses (stations, time) as dimensions but I would like it to use (lat, lon, time).

I looked online and found how to [swap dimensions](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.swap_dims.html#xarray.Dataset.swap_dims) but I could only find it applied to swapping one dimension.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (stations: 11, time: 7320)
Coordinates:
  * stations    (stations) int64 11425 11426 11427 11428 ... 11433 11434 11435
    lat         (stations) float64 39.54 39.36 39.24 39.07 ... 38.07 37.9 37.81
    lon         (stations) float64 -74.25 -74.4 -74.6 ... -75.19 -75.34 -75.51
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-02-01 ... 2010-02-06T01:59:00
Data variables:
    waterlevel  (time, stations) float64 0.0002405 0.0002313 ... -0.01266
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `station` coordinate a MultiIndex of the `lat` and `lon` coordinates using `set_index` (as explained [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/reshaping.html#set-and-reset-index)). In a second step you can then unstack the MultiIndex to make `lat` and `lon` the dataset dimensions. Note, however, that this will blow up the size of your dataset (unless the station are already on a regular grid), filling up grid points without a station with NaN values. For many applications, making the `station` dimension a MultiIndex of `lat` and `lon` should be enough.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={"waterlevels": (("station", "time"), np.random.rand(5, 20))},
    coords={
        "station": ("station", ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]),
        "lon": ("station", np.random.rand(5)),
        "lat": ("station", np.random.rand(5)),
        "time": pd.date_range(start="10-05-2021", periods=20, freq="d"),
    },
)

# Rename the station coordinate so that you don't overwrite it
ds = ds.rename_vars({"station": "station_id"})
# Create MultiIndex coordinate
ds_multiindex = ds.set_index(
    station=["lat", "lon"]
)
# Unstack the MultiIndex
ds_multiindex.unstack()
```